# control block diagram design

Tags: control-engineering, systems-design

I have a pump [m^3/(sV)], a tank [no units], a valve [m^2/s] and a level sensor [m/V]. The units are for the gains in the respective transfer functions. How should i connect my control block? Where should the takeoff point to the level sensor be?  I'm supposed to be using the pump to control the water height as measured by the level sensor.
Here's what i've come up with. The numerators of the transfer functions have gains with units displayed below the transfer functions.
[image]
These are the transfer functions for better understanding
[image]

How should i know where to put what? I've tried using unit analysis but it doesn't make any sense? I don't even know what the outputs of the controller should be, so i cant really do the analysis well enough.

Comment: You could at first think about it yourself, come up with a diagram, post it here and then we could help you enhance it. Searching or asking for something already made won’t basically help you !

Comment: what im asking is whether the process of designing a block diagram takes into account the units because all the configurations i've come up with dont make sense when you consider the units. Ive already thought about the valve being in series with the plant, what i dont know is how to check whether its correct. Thats what im asking, how do you know its the correct configuration?